# Unable to minimize emacs window on mac os

Tags: macos, emacs

I'm using emacs 24.1 from http://emacsformacosx.com/ on mac os 10.7. It works well but for some reason I'm unable to minimize emacs window. When I press the yellow button in the upper left corner window goes to the dock but then immediately restores on the same place.

Comment: [Aquamacs](http://aquamacs.org/) isn't an alternative for you?

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue on my system.

Comment: I have exactly the same problem for Aquamacs. It looks like [this](http://www.screencast.com/t/ni6hWfcW).

Comment: Sounds a lot like an issue affecting multiple or even all applications. What about other programs? Is it *really* limited to just Emacs and Aquamacs?

Comment: I started using Mac Os only three months ago. And so far this issue affects only Emacs and Aquamacs. I actually already tested it on another Mac under 10.8 developer preview and the same problem reproduced on it as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case this behaviour was caused by mouse-avoidance-mode line in my `.emacs` file:

```
(mouse-avoidance-mode (quote banish) nil (avoid))
```

I changed it to:

```
(mouse-avoidance-mode 'exile)
```

and now everything works fine.